# Incrementing a structs variable inside an array?

Tags: ruby

Cannot get user.points to increment.

```
Userspoints = Struct.new(:name, :points)

player = "placeholder"
array = []

user = Userspoints.new(player, 0)

array << user.name << user.points

found = array.index(user.name)
points = array[found + 1]

array[user.points += 50]

print array
```

Expected output: ["placeholder", 50]

Actual output: ["placeholder", 0]

Comment: Because you're updating the `points` property of the `user` object and not the `Fixnum` 0 in the array. Do: `array[found+1] += 50` to update the value in array.

Comment: @gingervititiis: And, in your code, if you would do a `print user.points`, you would also see the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to index the array by the result of the increment assignment. I think what you want is

```
...
array[found + 1] += 50
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get to the instruction

```
array[user.points += 50]
```

your array has the value "placeholder" at position 0 and 0 at position 1

So when you try to call the instruction with **user.points** you are trying to access the position 50 of your array that at the current time it doesn't exist.

In order to update your points you should do this

```
array[array.index(user.points)] += 50
```